# Simple e-commerce CMS (for a few products)

Tags: gratis, cms, ecommerce

To sell a few products online (10 maximum), I'm looking for a light free e-commerce CMS.

Here are some of my crtierias:

- Easy to configure (I tried Magento, and I don't want to configure categories, special prices, blocks and all that stuff …)
- Paypal support (and maybe Google Checkout)
- Relatively easy to skin
- Eventually, for later, a "name your price" feature (I may be able to develop it if it does not exists)
- PHP is preferred (so I can customize the CMS / develop modules)

The workflow I imagine is a simple product index, a product page, a checkout page and a confirmation email.

I tried Magento and PrestaShop, but they seem really heavy.

Comment: It must use PHP?

Comment: No, but as I'm a PHP developper, I will be more able to develop a module in PHP to make exactly what I want

Answer (score 2):

Magento would be your last resort according to your need. a lightweight, easy to setup, compatible with Paypal and Google checkout and with thousands of skins/Themes is [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/) with the use of [WooCommerce](http://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/) Plug-in. setting up an online store using them can take
less than one hour and you will be able to sell your products right away. Woocommerce will automatically set-up checkout page, user accounts, confirmation emails, product index and many features for you. it's also very SEO-friendly and Plugin-rich. you need to have a Linux web server with support for PHP.